# Does it effect my code if i remove new keyword and routes from following code

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

Please check my code, i want to setup my server using hapijs. Does it create any problem if i remove new keyword and routes.

```
const server = new Hapi.Server({
port: PORT,
routes: {
  log: {collect: true},
  cors: {
    origin: ['*'],
    headers: [
      'Accept', 'Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
    additionalHeaders: ['language', 'app-version', 'ios-app-version'],
  },
},
```

});

Comment: Why do you want to remove those lines ?

Comment: @metoikos tell me the difference, i just want to know difference if i don't use these lines?

Comment: What do you mean by "new keyword" ? The cors object represent the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing configuration https://hapijs.com/api/18.1.0#-routeoptionscors and log enable the collect of ... logs https://hapijs.com/api/18.1.0#-routeoptionslog

Answer (score 1):

With or without new keyword it returns the same object. There is no difference on Hapi basis.

You can create a hapi server instance like this

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');

const server = Hapi.server({
    port: 3000,
    host: 'localhost'
});
```

No need for new keyword or routes property.You can attach your routes later to your server instance.

Here is complete simple server setup that I copied from [hapijs.com](https://hapijs.com/tutorials)

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');

const server = Hapi.server({
    port: 3000,
    host: 'localhost'
});

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: (request, h) => {

        return 'Hello, world!';
    }
});

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{name}',
    handler: (request, h) => {

        return 'Hello, ' + encodeURIComponent(request.params.name) + '!';
    }
});

const init = async () => {

    await server.start();
    console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
};

process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {

    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
});

init();
```